# Allow only .png files using. I am having trouble writing conditional statement

Tags: jquery, file

```
function uploadFile(){
  if ($('.file')[1].files.length > 0) {
    if ($('.file')[1].files.extension == '.png') {      
      $('#publishersharebutton').trigger('click');
    } else {
      alert("Please select file");
    }     
  }            
}
```

Can anybody improve the above conditional statements for uploading only .png files? I am not sure whether `files.extension == '.png'` is correct. Thanks.

Comment: try to do an `alert($('.file')[1].files.extension)` right before the if, so that you know exactly how the extension looks like

Comment: @FreemanLambda Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.file').on('change', function () {
        var ext = $('.file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ['png']) == -1) {
            alert('invalid extension!');
        }
        else{
            alert('Valid extension');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="file" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: you can check multi type .['png','jpg',...]

Comment: If the code was executed correctly  Please confirm to help others

Comment: Please confirm and Vote @Alan.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is restricting file types on a file input on the client side then I recommend abandoning the javascript altogether and using the accept attribute on the html element.

```
<input type="file" accept=".png">
```

This has the advantage of filtering the file popup natively.

Comment: This is by far the most ideal solution, but be aware that it's not supported in Edge

Comment: Wow I didn't know, that but I tested it real quick in Edge with https://jsfiddle.net/4mh7742s/ and you are correct that it does not work in edge. It DOES work in IE and other browsers though. I guess that just proves Edge is not ready for mainline use yet.